# Debugging Perl Regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, debugging

I am trying to debug a few regular expressions using:

```
perl -Mre=debug file.pl
```

The *file.pl* script has many regular expression. Some of them are repeated. Using the above syntax, all the regexes in *file.pl* are being debugged.

Is there a way to tell Perl to debug only a particular regex in a script?

I am familiar with the [YAPE::Regex](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAPE::Regex) module, but that is not what I require. So please don’t suggest to use that.

Comment: Why not just comment out the other regexes, or run just the particular regex on the command line, via `perl -e` ?

Comment: the script is very compilcated(12000 LOC). If I will comment out any of regex then the execution will fail..also if I provide dummy values, then it will give unexpected results :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with many other pragmas, you can use [`no`](http://p3rl.org/no) to cancel previous `use`.

```
use re 'debug';

$str=~/\d{3}/;

no re 'debug';

$str=~/\d{3}/;
```

Answer (score 6):

> As of 5.9.5 the directive use re 'debug' and its equivalents are lexically scoped, as the other directives are.

Use:

```
{
    use re 'debug';
    # Debugged regexp here.
}
```

Comment: Is this also supported in 5.8.8? I am putting it under a condition but it is enabling it globally for all regex.

Comment: No, since version 5.9.5. In 5.8.8 you need use `no` statement.